# Automatic reconnect to internet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internet-connection

How can I programatically force system (Windows 7) to reconnect to internet? I need IP changed. I'm using USB Modem Huawei E1750

Comment: You IP address will be assigned by your ISP when using dial-up. You have no control over this.

Comment: Yes, my IP is assigned by ISP. I don't have control over this. But I think I have control do decide that I want to reconnect, right?

Comment: Yes but that won't change your IP --> your question states: "I need IP changed"

Comment: Does `ipconfig /renew` get you a new IP address without reconnecting? Does reconnecting? If not, you may need to change your device's MAC address (network connections, properties, configure, advanced) between reconnects. However it sounds like you're trying to do something malicious / avoid paying - do you really need to do this?

Comment: @PoweRoy: I just wrote "I need IP changed" to explain why I want to reconnect. The question is "How can I programatically force system (Windows 7) to reconnect to internet?"

Comment: I don't want do do anything malicious, just download some data that this site discloses for free. They even don't have option to pay them for unlimited access. Thay just don't want when somebody visits them too much. But if i reconnect manually is OK so what is wrong with reconnecting automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance you'll get the same external IP even if you do reconnect, that is up to your ISP.  As for your internal (on your router if you have one) IP, you can change that by changing your IP address in the Windows 7 settings.

Why do you want this ability - sounds like you're trying to get around an IP filter/limit of a website?

**EDIT:**
Well, not sure if this will help, but a simple Google search turned this up: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/260772-enable-disable-lan-connection

Comment: I'm getting different IP every time. And yes, I need some data to download from web page and they only allow 100 hits per IP.

Comment: @Jacek: Use a proxy, would be my first thought.

Comment: But if I used a proxy I still would need to change it every 100 hits. And if I use any public IP it is not guaranteed that someone else isn't visiting that page or even worse... that proxy is permanently blocked.